# Angular JS ng-style and Internet Explorer 8

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, angularjs

I have a problem I can't seem to understand.

In IE8 the directive ng-style doesn't seem to work at all. I'm using it to set the width of an element. On all other browsers it works fine.

On IE8, inspecting the element with the crappy F12 tool, the style property is entirely missing.

Anyone can tell me if there's a workaround? The angularjs version I'm using is the stable version at the time of writing (1.0.2)

Thanks

Comment: Can you post a jsFiddle? It's working fine in IE8 mode for me: http://jsfiddle.net/g/NLrYx/1/

Comment: It is indeed working. I'm using a variable from my $scope to set the width in my code. I can't reproduce the whole thing in a fiddle, but I'll experiment more and update the topic.

Comment: check the js console for errors and the interpreted DOM in the IE debug window, I've already seen IE8 having a hard time with complicated text inside attributes.

Comment: Alright, the issue was with another script messing up, now it works fine in IE8, however it doesn't work at all in IE7, meaning that it seems that angular engine doesn't even start. Even the fiddle you posted doesn't work in IE7. Is there anything more to do to make angular work in IE7?

Comment: Well it loads fine for me, I've only tried IE9 in IE7 mode (don't have a real IE7), but it works the same way most of the time. EDIT: oups you're right, it's not completely working, the color binding works, but the {{}} tag don't

Comment: @MatteoMosca I'm having a similar issue.  I have $scope.test = "test" and {{test}} will not appear on the HTML page.  Which script messed things up for you?  How did you fix it for IE8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found why {{ }} wasn't working in IE7: you have to polyfill JSON.stringify because it's used to display objects and IE7 don't have it, if you display a string it's working:

http://jsfiddle.net/NLrYx/3/

More info on IE7 compat: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie

JSON script: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js

Comment: Very strange. Because I just solved it, but in a different way. I didn't polyfill anything, I just put id="ng-app" on my root div and it started working in IE7, without stringifying anything.

Comment: can you post a fiddle? it doesn't sounds right at all, you are probably bootstrapping angular twice and IE7 don't have JSON so trying to {{}} on an object will always fail without a polyfill.

Comment: That's not it. I noticed that in IE7 I have 2 ways to bootstrap: either do it via code (using angular.bootstrap method) or via the attributes, but the ng-app attribute alone doesn't work. It also needs id="ng-app" in order to bootstrap.