# Carousel image not displaying in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, internet-explorer-8, carousel, angular-ui

I'm trying to use the [AngularUI-Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.com/bootstrap/) (especially the carousel directive) in my app.

It works fine in Chrome, FF, Opera and IE9 but in IE8 it doesn't display the `<img>` tag inside the `<slide>` tag (or in my case `<div slide></div>`).

```html
<div carousel interval="5000">
    <div ng-repeat="image in dealerdetails.images" active="slide.active" slide>
        <img src="{{image}}" />
    </div>
</div>
```

When I just display `{{image}}m` it shows me the path to my image. That's correct but if I try to use `<img src="{{image}}">` or with `ng-src`, it doesn't display at all.

Does anyone else have the same problem? It's just in IE8 and 7. IE7 is not important but I have to fix it in IE8.

Comment: Seems related to [this entry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12642188/angular-js-ng-style-and-internet-explorer-8).

Comment: not quite. When I display the {{}} without the <img> tag, it renders. Also all polyfills are included (json3.min.js)

Comment: @Marek123 could open an issue in https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues for this one? Not sure what is going on but if this is a bug it should be fixed.

Comment: Try adding `no-transition="true"` tag to the `<div carousel>` and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
<img src="{{img}}" />
```

is never a good idea in angular

Give this a try:

```
<img ng-src="{{img}}" />
```

That doesn't explain why is DOES work in other browsers, but letting angular do its thing with the ngSrc directive is a good idea in general

Unfortunately I'm on Linux and don't have IE8 access so I can't test for you.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few patches floating around to fix this.  I had to use a combination of this [patch](https://github.com/redaemn/bootstrap/commit/19ab7e5f4cee7814589da175d5581f5a1e1d222f#src/carousel/carousel.js) and using div carousel rather than the carousel tag to get it working in IE8.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me: (with jquery-1.10.2 only in this page and with a div parent before the image)

```
                 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

                 <div carousel interval="3000">
                  <div slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="slide.active">
                    <div style="text-align: center; align: center">
                        <img src="/img/articles/{{slide.image}}" alt="{{slide.title}}"  style="margin: auto; text-align: center; align: center"/>
                    </div>          
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                      <p>{{slide.tittle}}</p>
                      <p>{{slide.content}}</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
```